# Как запустить браузер с определенными капабилитис

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Подскажите, пожалуйста.
Написала следующий код:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\alsa1118\\Desktop\\chromedriver_win32 (1)"
        + "\\chromedriver.exe");
Platform platform = Platform.WINDOWS;
Capabilities capabilities1 = new DesiredCapabilities("Chrome", "73", platform);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities1);
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\alsa1118\\Desktop\\chromedriver_win32"
        + "\\chromedriver.exe");
Capabilities capabilities2 = new DesiredCapabilities("Chrome", "404", platform);
WebDriver driver2 = new ChromeDriver(capabilities2);
driver2.get("http://www.google.com");
```

По моим предположениям должен подниматься браузер хром, навигироваться на страничку. Потом второй браузер пытается подняться, но так как версии браузера, которую я передаю в конструктор, не существует, программа должна завершаться с эксепшеном (ну или что то вроде этого).
Моя программа открывает 2 браузера. Подскажите, почему это происходит, и как сделать правильно. Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Честно говоря не совсем понятно, чего вы хотите получить в итоге. Проверьте версию второго открывшегося браузера через меню вверху. Как мне кажется, если вы пишите версию выше текущей, просто открывается текущая. Или я вас неправильно понял :)

Comment: WebDriver driver2 = new ChromeDriver(capabilities2); Является Deprecated в 3 селениуме, во вторых согласен полностью с первым коментарием, браузер откроется с последней версией которая установлена в вашей системе. так же следует заметить, что Хром не откроет Вам никакую предыдущую версию при таком коде.